# Working on old haskell project using the latest package index from Hackage

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

Lets assume that I have updated to the all the package index of my cabal using

```
cabal update
```

Now, let's say I have an old project (Yesod in my case) which I get and want to work upon.

So, I go inside the directory and issue the following commands:

```
cd project
cabal sandbox init
cabal configure
```

The above command throws a lot of dependency problems like this:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
aeson >=0.6 && <0.8,
attoparsec >=0.11 && <1.0,
.......... This goes on
```

Then I try this command:

```
cabal install --only-dependencies
```

This doesn't help much either and throws the following error:

```
trying: yesod-static-1.2.4 (dependency of project-0.0.1.0)
trying: wai-app-static-3.0.0 (dependency of yesod-static-1.2.4)
next goal: warp (dependency of project-0.0.1.0)
rejecting: warp-3.0.0.1, 3.0.0 (conflict: project => warp>=2.1 && <2.2)
rejecting: warp-2.1.5.2, 2.1.5.1, 2.1.5, 2.1.4.1, 2.1.4, 2.1.3.3, 2.1.3.2,
2.1.3.1, 2.1.3, 2.1.2.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.1.2, 2.1.1.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.0 (conflict:
wai-app-static => warp>=3.0 && <3.1)
------------ This goes on
```

What is the general approach to solve this type of problem ?

Comment: For starters, try relaxing the dependency on the `warp` package in your cabal file. Possibly, try to depend on `warp==3.*'.

Comment: @creichert I can play around with cabal file to make it work, but I was wondering if there was some other method.

Comment: @Sibi: The first step is to try giving cabal the flag `--allow-newer`.  This means it will ignore all upper version bounds.  Presuming that works, you should update the dependencies in your .cabal file to the latest version of everything.  If you want to use the old versions, I think you'll need to do some manual intervention.  The `yesod` maintainers don't believe in including upper bounds in version dependencies, which means that cabal will try to install newer, incompatible versions of dependencies.  You can add `--constraint="yesod-static == x"` etc. where `x` is known-good version.